# How to apply to a numpy array special function based on neighbour elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to apply a function to a 2d-array that must work like commulative sum, but instead uses **max()** function applied to upper, left and upper-left-diagonal neighbours and element itself. It should start from upper-left element and commulate previous results for calculation the next element. Is there a way to do it without nested loops?

**Example:**

```
>>> x = np.arange(9)[np.random.permutation(9)].reshape((3,3))
>>> x
array([[3, 4, 8],
       [0, 6, 5],
       [7, 2, 1]])

>>> res = np.zeros(x.shape)
>>> for i in range(0, x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, x.shape[1]):
            if i==0:
                if j==0:
                    res[i,j] = x[i,j]
                else:
                    res[i,j] = max(x[i,j], res[i,j-1])
            else:
                if j==0:
                    res[i,j] = max(x[i,j], res[i-1,j])
                else:
                    res[i,j] = max(x[i,j], res[i-1,j], res[i,j-1], res[i-1,j-1])
>>> res
array([[3., 4., 8.],
       [3., 6., 8.],
       [7., 7., 8.]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because values of "further" *res* elements depend on values
of "previous" elements (computed earlier), you can not use Numpy
vectorization, as it depends only on elements of the source array.

But you can simplify your code as follows:

```
res = x.copy()
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    i1 = max(i-1, 0)      # Start of row range
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        j1 = max(j-1, 0)  # Start of column range
        res[i,j] = res[i1:i+1, j1:j+1].max()
```

​
The result is:

```
array([[3, 4, 8],
       [3, 6, 8],
       [7, 7, 8]])
```

Note that due to `res = x.copy()` the result has the same *dtype* as
the original array.

Answer (score 0):

The numpy has cumsum() built-in function, which we can use here if we provide axis as "1" , then it will give cu. sum of the columns , if you want the cu. sum of the rows you can use axis as "0"

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(9)[np.random.permutation(9)].reshape((3,3))
print(x)
x =np.cumsum(x,dtype=float,axis=1)
print(x)

Output:
[[0 2 8]
[3 1 6]
[5 4 7]]
[[ 0.  2. 10.]
[ 3.  4. 10.]
[ 5.  9. 16.]]
```